# SignalR works on local IIS but not on production server, Websocket not recognized

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, websocket, signalr

I'm using SignalR for real-time interaction. It works well on my local IIS, when I open Google Chrome's DevTool and check the Network tab, in the WS section I can see the request as in the picture below. All the requests also appear in the XHR tab.

However when I deploy it on a server with IIS 10, functionally my code still works, but on WS tab there's nothing at all, all the requests only appear on the XHR tab.

Did I miss any environment setup? And does that affect my performance? Thank you so much for your help.

[image]

Comment: Is WebSocket Protocol activated on production server? check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

Comment: @Moein Mohammadian that solved my issue, thank you so much:D

Comment: You're welcome, so I'll post it as answer. @Liberty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate WebSocket Protocol on production server IIS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support